# How can I clear the cache for the params of a custom component?

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, cache

I am working on a custom component and it works as intended as long as I do not have cache enabled.

In the admin section of the component, I have a view that can change the "component params":

```
$params = JComponentHelper::getParams( 'com_example' );
$params->set( 'customsetting', 'test' );

$componentid = JComponentHelper::getComponent('com_example')->id;
$table = JTable::getInstance('extension');
$table->load($componentid);
$table->bind(array('params' => $params->toString()));

if (!$table->check()) {
    echo $table->getError();
}
if (!$table->store()) {
    echo $table->getError();
}
```

and load that setting with

```
$params = JComponentHelper::getParams( 'com_example' );
$setting = $params->get( 'customsetting' );
```

As I mentioned, this works without cache. But with cache, I cannot update the setting.

I guess I need to clear the cache after I change the component parameters, but I could not figure out how.

I tried `parent::cleanCache('com_hbmanager');`, but it had no effect. https://docs.joomla.org/Cache also didn't help me finding a solution.

Is there a way to clear the cache for the parameters of a component?

Comment: I've just come across this question - did you get it sorted? I tried it out and it did cache it when the system Page Cache plugin was enabled, as you describe. However to get round it I cleaned the cache for "_system" before I read the parameters with getParams(). Looking at the code in ComponentHelper.php, that's what is passed to getCache() to load the parameters in the load() function.

Comment: I didn't find a way to do it yet. I will try your suggestion when I get a chance

Answer (score 1):

Are you using custom caching or built-in ? I've never had problems with component cache.

I've put your snippet inside com_content and it worked despite cache was on.

**You can delete all site cache via model:**

```
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_cache/models', 'Cache');
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Cache', 'CacheModel');
$model->clean();
//$model->clean('_system'); SYSTEM_CACHE_ONLY
```

This is equivalent to:

```
$cache = JCache::getInstance('output', 
            [
                'defaultgroup'=>'',             
                'cachebase' => JPATH_SITE.'/cache' or JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR for admin cache
            ]);
$cache->clean();
```

System cache will rebuild _system as quick as you hit administrator area again :)

Comment: Thanks :) I don't recall all the details since the question is over 3 years old. I definitely did not use any custom caching. If you tried it just now, we also probably used different versions of Joomla.